# $.getJSON's success handler not being called

Tags: jquery, json, jsonp

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript">
      $(function(){

        $.getJSON('http://localhost:8080/privateTraining/getTrainingsJson?callback=?',            
            function(data) {
                console.log("success");
                alert(data);
        });

    });
```

here response is getting But the success function never runs.

Here getJson is a remote server call.

when i check with firbug , response giving valid json data (json data being checked with http://jsonlint.com/ and its giving result as **Valid JSON**)

Even tried:

```
    $.ajax({
        dataType: "jsonp", //set this to json
        url: "http://localhost:8080/privateTraining/getTrainingsJson",
        success: function(data) 
        {
            var myObj = data;
            console.log(myObj); //to see the object
        }
    });
```

but gives same result.. success function is not executing

Comment: JSON is not valid JSONP. So if you tell jQuery to expect JSONP (which both, the `callback=?` in the URL and `dataType: "jsonp"` will do), then the response will be evaluated incorrectly and the success callback won't be called. So, what does the server return, is it JSONP or JSON? If it is JSON, remove the `callback=?` and set `dataType` to `"json"`. Now, if you are making a cross-domain request (i.e. `http://localhost:8080/` does not serve the page the request is made from), you'd have to use JSONP, in which case you have to setup your server to return JSONP (you could enable CORS instead).

Comment: Since we don't know what the server really returns and what your network setup is, guessing is the best we can do.

Comment: @FelixKling: server returns json data

Answer (score 1):

Try removing "?callback=?" from your url:  I seem to remember that that has something to do with jasonP (cross domain)

JQuery is probably looking for a function called "?" instead of calling your supplied success function.

Comment: jQuery will substitute the `?` with the name of the function it generates,  and it will call the success callback inside that function (if everything else is correct of course).

Comment: @monda, if you change "success" to "complete", does it fire?